# PHP execute shell command that initiates wine desktop and display output in the browser

Tags: php, wine, replit

I'm currently using PHP to run a shell command that initiates a WINE-based desktop. My goal is to create a web-based application that can display that desktop in the browser. However, with my current code:

```php
<?php
$output = shell_exec("TERM=xterm
export NIXPKGS_ALLOW_UNFREE=1
cd /home/runner
wineboot
wine explorer.exe");
echo $output
?>
```

I *do* get the output, but not in the browser. It is instead displayed in my hosting source's output section (I'm using replit for testing)[image]

Once I run the file, the web application is killed completely, and I can't run it anymore at all, replaced with a 404 page. And, the output stays active forever. Through my testing, I now have at least 5 projects that have had the same issue and can no longer be used. If there is a solution, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Wait.. you want to run a virtual desktop _in the brower_?? Seriously?

Comment: yes, and I know it is possible as I have seen services that can do it. Problem is, they are too expensive for me personally

Comment: That approach is doomed to fail: You're php script runs on your server. Starting wine on your server will not result in a http response that a browser could render.

Comment: Is there a javascript alternative?

Comment: You should check on the internet...

Comment: The general very high-level concept is that you are streaming video. The specifics vary for each implementation, both server-side and client-side, but that's where you'd start.